# How to register a user for the ejabberd website (Debian)

Tags: authentication, ejabberd

I tried using the **ejabberd register**
command but it tells me command not found

I updated to 20.04 and now i cant login anymore

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the script is called ejabberdctl:

```
$ ejabberdctl register someusername yourserver somepassword
```

Other idea: if you have mod_register enabled and it allows registration, you can register an account using a Jabber client.